# How can I have a new thread "take over" stdin?

Tags: c, io, stdin

In a program I am writing, I have a main thread that contains a loop for accepting console input.  However, at some point a new thread is created that also tries to read from stdin.  There is a variable that indicates that this other thread has started, but fgets is still waiting for input in the main thread, so the first console input entered after the new thread started is erroneously read by the main thread instead of the new thread.

Is there some way to solve this?

One thing I have tried is (in the main thread):

```
while(foo) {
   if(busy) continue;
   fgets(input,200,stdin);
   if(busy) {
      fputs(input,stdin);
   } else {
      // do whatever was supposed to be done with input intended for main thread
   }
}
```

But I appear to have a misunderstanding of how streams work because the other fgets call does not read the data written via fputs.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Are you sure there's not a better design that keeps all of the I/O on the same thread?

Comment: That would be ideal.  I guess I was having trouble seeing the forest for the trees.

I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean variable protected an appropriate synchronization primitive. Initialize it to false. When a thread needs to ask a user a question and get an answer, wait for the variable to become 'false' (as appropriate for the synchronization primitive you chose) and then set it to true. Do all the output and get all the input you need. Then set the variable to 'false' and unblock any threads waiting (as appropriate for the synchronization primitive you chose).

For pthreads, a mutex and condition variable is probably best. For Windows, a critical section and auto reset event is probably best.

Your question does lack some details that may suggest a different answer. How is the user supposed to interact with a program when he can't be sure which of two separate code paths will get the input he types? If he types something and then hits 'enter', which code path it goes to would seem to depend on whether he hits 'enter' before the other thread is ready or not, which would seem to make an unusable program. In almost every realistic case, you will need to prompt the user and then wait for a response and then release input and output together.

Comment: Thanks for the input!  This will definitely be useful at some point, but for this program I have refactored to have only one thread be dealing with stdin.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, here is how I solved this.

Instead of having both threads be waiting for console input, I now have only one thread wait for input and delegate the handling of that input to functions specific to the program state.

The snippet above becomes:

```
while(foo) {
   fgets(input,200,stdin);
   if(busy) {
      busyStuff(input);
   } else {
      nonBusyStuff(input);
   }
}
```

and no other pthread that has an fgets call is ever created.